# Passing message between 2 addon scripts

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I'm abstracting away the code to focus on the core question. I have a `main.js` file, which requires a second file, `optionsmod.js`.

I'd like to be able to send a message from `optionsmod.js` to `main.js`, so that `main.js` can then go on to do other things. I don't know how to do this...

Here is an example that does't work.

main.js:

```
var optionsmod = require("optionsmod.js");
var self = require("sdk/self");

optionsmod.init();

self.port.on("message",function(){
        console.log("message received");
});
```

optionsmod.js:

```
var self = require("sdk/self");
function init(){
        console.log("here in init"); 
        //FOR THIS EXAMPLE, I'VE MADE THE CALL HERE. BUT WONT BE NORMALLY
        sendMessage();
}

function sendMessage(){
        self.port.emit("message");
        console.log("message sent");
}

exports.init = init;
```

The code I've added doesn't work, but is there a way to do something similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no default way of passing messages between modules. It is quite easy to get something to happen in **optionsmod.js** when an event occurs in **main.js**. Simply export the function and call it from **main.js**. It isn't so straightforward the other way around, though. Two ways I handle this are by passing callback functions and [creating event targets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Tutorials/Creating_event_targets). Here's an example with a callback function:

**main.js**

```
var optionsmod = require("optionsmod.js");
var eventCallback = function(message) {
  console.log('message received: '+message);
};
optionsmod.init(eventCallback);
```

**optionsmod.js**

```
exports.init = function(eventCallback) {
  foo.on('bar', function() {
    eventCallback('the message');
    console.log('message sent');
  });
};
```

The alternative is to export `foo`, then call `foo.on` from **main.js**, but that probably defeats the whole purpose of writing a separate module, in which case the docs I linked to will be helpful. Frankly, you could probably use those docs to create your own proprietary messaging system, but I think you're better off thinking in the above terms.

Comment: Thanks. I'll look into this tomorrow. I didn't want to go for callback s originally (i've forgotten why), but it looks like it may be the way to go.